# repeating elements in common lisp

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

I am try to create a function with `two arguments x and y` which creates a `list of y times repeated elements X` but im getting confused on how to do it which or which method to use i think list compression  can do but i want a shorter and simple method for example i want my simple code to be like this

```
if y = 4
 and x = 7
 result is list of elements (7, 7, 7, 7)
```

how can i go about it any ideas?? books links or anything that will give me a clue i tried searching but i have not been lucky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it's in Scheme but the general idea should be easy enough to translate to Common Lisp:

```
(define (repeat x y)
  (if (zero? y)
      null
      (cons x
            (repeat x (sub1 y)))))
```

**EDIT:**

Now, in Common Lisp:

```
(defun repeat (x y)
  (if (zerop y)
      nil
      (cons x
            (repeat x (1- y)))))
```

Comment: if one of the results from `if` is going to be `nil` anyway, it seems cleaner to me to negate the condition and just leave off the second ("else") argument, which defaults to `nil` if not specified:  `(if (not (zerop y)) (cons x (repeat x (1- y))))`.

Comment: @MarkReed I dislike one-armed `if`s. They're forbidden in Racket for a good reason ;)

Answer (score 23):

You can use [make-list](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_lis.htm) with the *initial-element* key:

```
CL-USER> (make-list 10 :initial-element 8)
   (8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8)
```

While a good example of how you can code such a function by yourself is provided by Óscar answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer