# manipulating lists in common lisp

Tags: functional-programming, common-lisp, clisp

how does one create a list from a list,what function can i really use i was thinking of using `mapcar or maplist with cons` together but im not getting any fruitful results,lets say i have a  `list (a b)`  then i want a function that will create a list containing the same elements but they should be inform of lists like this  `((a) (b))` ,any ideas on how i can solve this problem?? is there a function a use to it?

```
if i have a list(a b)
the result should be ((a)(b))
```

thanks guys

Comment: I don't speak lisp, but you should be able to do something like `map (lambda x: cons(x,nil))`. Hope that's understandable...

Comment: this sounds like another fake question from a bunch of fake stackoverflow accounts. All have extremely poor spelling, wrong Lisp syntax, show no own effort and ask trivial questions.

Comment: @RainerJoswig "fake question"? What have I missed?

Comment: @RainerJoswig how is it fake???the syntax is not the lisp syntax its just an example on how i want it to look like,just trying to learn here i will appreciate if you just help me  out if you have ideas thanks

Comment: @fableal thanks for the contribution :)

Comment: @wvxvw: this is a similar question by another user just an hour earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442008/repeating-elements-in-common-lisp. Same spelling mistakes, same formatting mistakes, no effort put into it, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is this:

```
(defun listify(ls) 
    (mapcar (lambda (elem) (list elem))  ls))
```

**EDIT**

Which is the same as (Thanks to @RainerJoswig):

```
(defun listify(ls) 
    (mapcar #'list ls))
```

And if you do:

```
(listify (list 1 2 3))
```

or

```
(listify '(1 2 3))
```

The output will be:

```
((1) (2) (3))
```

Comment: (lambda (elem) (list elem)) is just #'list

Comment: No need for the down vote. Jeez.

Comment: The syntax is `#'list`, not `'#list`.

Comment: @Xach my bad, fixed :P. Lousy copy-past skills.